# i am getting this error even after executing this command "npm install express-hbs --save"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, hbs

[image]

Hey guys I am getting error even after executing the above command if there is any other command to resolve this error please let me know

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express-hbs'
```

Comment: Can you share your install log as well?

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes @MarioG8  I got the answer. Thank You!

Comment: @dinindu I resolve the error. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Before You start using the `package` - [express-hbs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-hbs), You must install it properly, most likely You installed the package in the wrong place, **outside** of the `project` folder.

In the `root` project folder, run the command:

- `npm install express-hbs`
- try again to run `nodemon`